# Javascript form control

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with select fields like this:

```
<select name="consegnaauto1"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto2"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto3"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto4"> .. </select>
```

I need to control with JavaScript if at least 1 of this select field has been selected.
I do it in that way:

```
for(i=0; i<13; i++) {
  if (myForm.consegnaauto[i].value != 0) {
      k=1;
      break;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't run. Can you help me please?

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the value of the "myForm" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that myForm is your forml object, you should use this code

```
for(i=1; i<=13; i++) {
  if (myForm['consegnaauto' + i].value != 0) {
      k=1;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

Add a function triggering onchange in each select:

```
<select name="consegnaauto1" onchange="changedSelect()"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto2" onchange="changedSelect()"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto3" onchange="changedSelect()"> .. </select>
<select name="consegnaauto4" onchange="changedSelect()"> .. </select>
```

In this function, you increment a global variable:

```
var select_changes = 0;

function changedSelect(){
     select_changes++;
}
```

On your condition, simply verify if your variable is >= 1:

```
if(select_changes >= 1){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a flag

```
var flag=false
for(i=0; i<13; i++) {
  if (myForm.consegnaauto[i].value != 0) {
      k=1;
      flag=true
      break;
  }
}
return flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea here just replace the checkbox with select:

```
$(function(){ 

$("#btn").click(function(){

    var formVar = document.forms["f"];
    var allInputs = formVar["input[]"];
    var len = allInputs.length;
    var anyChecked = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
       if (allInputs[i].checked){
          anyChecked = true;
          break;
       }

    if (!anyChecked) 
        alert("all checkboxes are empty!");

});

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kmWwa/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jQuery for this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var $isSelected false;
    var $dropDownList = $('form :select');
    $dropDownList.each(function () {
        var $select = $(this);
        if ($select.is(":selected")) {
            $isSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    });
   return $isSelected;
});
```

The variable "$dropDownList" is being populated with all of the select elements of the form. When the form is being submitted, it'll look for if a select item is selected. If the variable $isSelected is false, then no items were selected, and the form won't submit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, you are fantastic and very fast :)

I have solved the problem with this solution:

```
for(i=1; i<=13; i++) {
  if (myForm['consegnaauto' + i].value != 0) {
    k=1;
    break;
  }
  else {
      alert("Indicare la Località di Riconsegna.");
  return false;
  break;
  }
}
```

Simple and effective!
Thank you very much! nice weekend!
bye bye